# How to connect to Oracle DB in shell script to execute multiple SQL queries

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to connect Oracle DB to execute multiple SQL scripts and am using the DB properties file to get the database connection properties also it has the date parameters passed from shell script, I used below to execute but it gives me an error stating invalid connection.

```
......
     for (( i=1;i<=$Dbcount;i++ ))
        do
    sqlplus -S ${user1}@$CONNECTIONNAME_$i/${Password} <<-EOF &
    spool /data/sqlcsvwaydb_$i.csv
    @query.sql $date1 $date2
    exit
    EOF
.......
```

But when I use same connection with below code it does execute it. Is there anything wrong in above method? Note I used DB properties file to get the DB count and user password extra.

```
............
sqlplus -S ${user1}@$CONNECTIONNAME_${i}/${Password} @query.sql
............
```

Comment: What is the actual, exact error message? There's a reason oracle includes error codes with their messages.

Comment: Invalid connection, showing oracle db connection ways.

Comment: I asked for the "actual, exact error message".  I don't find "Invalid connection, showing oracle db connection ways." in any error message reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `user/password@connection`

Also I'd suggest to put `spool`  and `exit` into the same sql script

Comment: But I am able to connect with this method.${user1}@$CONNECTIONNAME_${i}/${Password @query.sql &,.  But I have requirement to based on db count it should loop and create multiple CSV files, so I am working on the another method.

Comment: @Naidu5 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12015.htm#BACBIHAF

Comment: " loop and create multiple CSV files" - so what's the problem? just add input parameters like spoolfilename. Read these 2 my posts: http://orasql.org/2013/04/09/sqlplus-tips-3-iterators-and-recursions/ and http://orasql.org/2013/04/17/sqlplus-tips-4-branching-execution/

Comment: "But I am able to connect with this method".  Your original question said you were getting a _connection_ error.  Now you seem to be asking about fulfilling a requirement _after_ you _successfully_ connect.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to break your script down into pieces, then – proving each part in turn, build it out piece by piece.

First, just a simple proof that the loop control itself does what you expect: I named the script ‘doit.sh’.  For the first iteration, I simply populate all of the environment variables that you referenced, then simply execute the loop with some ‘echo’ to prove what it is generating:

====

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
    echo $i
  done
```

And executing it

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
1
2
3

oracle:oklacity$
```

====
So, we know the loop control itself works, let’s see how it expands your connection string:

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
   echo Connecting with ${user1}@$CONNECTIONNAME_$i/${Password}
  done
```

And executing it:

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
Connecting with scott@1/tiger
Connecting with scott@2/tiger
Connecting with scott@3/tiger

oracle:oklacity$
```

Well, there’s your first issue, you are not getting the $CONNECTIONNAME expanded properly.  Let’s fix that by putting curly brackets around it

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
   echo Connecting with ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password}
  done
```

And executing it:

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
Connecting with scott@oklacity_1/tiger
Connecting with scott@oklacity_2/tiger
Connecting with scott@oklacity_3/tiger
```

Now that we have fixed your first problem, let’s add a simple connection to the database. I notice you are using the loop control number as part of your database connection string, so I’ve create three entries in my tnsnames.ora to match the example 3 iterations in my script. They all point to the same database, but for this exercise that doesn’t matter.

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
oklacity =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vbdb112-01)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oklacity)
    )
  )

oklacity_1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vbdb112-01)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oklacity)
    )
  )

oklacity_2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vbdb112-01)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oklacity)
    )
  )

oklacity_3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = vbdb112-01)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oklacity)
    )
  )
```

And we add the actual connection with sqlplus to our script.  Again I had to add curly brackets around an environment variable name:

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
   echo Connecting with ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password}
   sqlplus -s ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password} <<-EOF &
     show user
EOF
  done
```

And executing it

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
Connecting with scott@oklacity_1/tiger
Connecting with scott@oklacity_2/tiger
Connecting with scott@oklacity_3/tiger

oracle:oklacity$ USER is "SCOTT"
USER is "SCOTT"
USER is "SCOTT"
```

But what’s this?  We executed the loop 3 timses, but only got 2 outputs from sqlplus.  And the shell 'echo' are grouped separately from the sqlplus 'prompt'. And I had to manually hit ‘enter’ to get out of the loop.  That’s because you put an ‘&’ at the end of the line invoking sqlplus.  What was that all about?  Let’s fix it.

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
   echo Connecting with ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password}
   sqlplus -s ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password} <<-EOF 
     show user
EOF
  done
```

And executing it

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
Connecting with scott@oklacity_1/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
Connecting with scott@oklacity_2/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
Connecting with scott@oklacity_3/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
```

Now I have fixed two syntax issues with your original and so far everything is working.  Now let’s add in the calling of the sql script from sqlplus.  You are passing it two command line parms, so I will write a simple sql script to show what ever is passed to it.

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat query.sql
prompt First parm is &1
prompt Second parm is &2
exit

oracle:oklacity$
```

And the shell script with the call to query.sql added:

```
oracle:oklacity$ cat doit.sh
#!/bin/sh
DBcount=3
date1='8-Aug-2020'
date2='10-Aug-2020'
user1='scott'
CONNECTIONNAME='oklacity'
Password='tiger'
#
for (( i=1;i<=$DBcount;i++ ))
  do
   echo Connecting with ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password}
   sqlplus -s ${user1}@${CONNECTIONNAME}_$i/${Password} <<-EOF 
     show user
     @query.sql $date1 $date2
EOF
  done

oracle:oklacity$
```

And finally, the complete execution:

```
oracle:oklacity$ doit.sh
Connecting with scott@oklacity_1/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
First parm is 8-Aug-2020
Second parm is 10-Aug-2020
Connecting with scott@oklacity_2/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
First parm is 8-Aug-2020
Second parm is 10-Aug-2020
Connecting with scott@oklacity_3/tiger
USER is "SCOTT"
First parm is 8-Aug-2020
Second parm is 10-Aug-2020

oracle:oklacity$
```